# Why do I get None when writing to Exif data

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, exif

I'm working on a Django project where the user uploads an image and then they are able to edit the EXIF data and download the edited data written tot the image.

When writing the data back to the image I am getting `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`

It's been quite complicated to work on, but I'll try and get to the point and relevant code. I had to turn the data received from the form into a dictionary containing keys() corresponding to ExifTAG codes.

I'm now following this excellent guide https://blog.matthewgove.com/2022/05/13/how-to-bulk-edit-your-photos-exif-data-with-10-lines-of-python/ by Matthew Gove to write the data back to the image.

I can successfully create the PILLOW_TAGS list and VALUES (the print to console), and i'm filtering any `None` `k/v` so pretty stuck on why i'm getting `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`

Any help appreciated.

EDIT - if I 'hardcode' the PILLOW_TAGS and VALUES lists I do not get Nonetype error and the data is written. For example this does not give Nonetype error.

```
             PILLOW_TAGS = [315, 33432,]
             VALUES = ['foo', 'bar']
```

Full relevant code

```
            PILLOW_TAGS = list(filter(None, image_exif_data_with_codes.keys()))
            print("KEYS",PILLOW_TAGS)
            
            VALUES = list(filter(None, image_exif_data_with_codes.values()))
            print("values",VALUES)
            
            pillow_img = PillowImage.open(image.image.path)
            img_exif = pillow_img.getexif()
           
            for tag, value in zip(PILLOW_TAGS, VALUES):
                img_exif[tag] = value
            
            for tag in PILLOW_TAGS:
                try:
                    english_tag = ExifTags.TAGS[tag]
                    value = img_exif[tag]
                except:
                    continue
                print("{}: {}".format(english_tag, value))
           
            pillow_img.save(image.image.path, exif=img_exif)
            image.save()
```

Traceback

````
  File "C:\....\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\...\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\...\core\views.py", line 128, in test_view
    pillow_img.save(image.image.path, exif=img_exif)
  File "C:\...\.venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2439, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "C:\...\.venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py", line 777, in _save
    exif = exif.tobytes()
  File "C:\..\.venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 3792, in tobytes
    and ExifTags.IFD.Interop in value
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable```
````

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. In any case, the question you should be asking is "Why do I get `None` here?".

Comment: This will not solve your problem, but to omit None keys and values, do this instead: `filtered_dict2 = dict((k, v) for k, v in image_exif_data_with_codes.items() if k is not None and v is not None)`. This is to give you the peace of mind that keys and values are processed together, in the same order. By using .keys() and .values() separately, in some cases values can be returned in a different order than keys.

Comment: Please add the full program output, including the full error message with the traceback to the question.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the replies, Ulrich Eckhardt, I will edit my question and expand on it somewhat when I get chance later. Thanks for the link though I had not read that, my apologies.

Just to add, I've checked for type() within both PILLOW_TAGS and VALUES lists and each element is str or int, not None. Also checked that PillowImage is opening the image which it is.

@pts I need to create two separate lists not a new dictionary, but yea thanks for that. Also I've added the traceback.

Comment: As soon as you have a known correct dict, you can get its keys and values as needed.

Comment: Maybe only some of the tags are problematic (even if not None). To figure out which tag, change only one tag, save the file, change the next tag etc.

Comment: Ah, yes of course, sorry @pts I've updated my question. Some tags contain byte objects, even though they are strings, eg some look like this foo = b'\x02\x00\x02\x00\x00\x01\x01\x02' ...... but i;ve checked their type() and they return str. grrr

Comment: Given what you've told us, a good place to start would be to log `repr(image_exif_data_with_codes.keys())` and `repr(image_exif_data_with_codes.values())`.

Comment: BTW, triple-backticks only start and end multi-line code blocks here (and other places using github-flavored markdown) when they start and end on a line with nothing else -- that's why your last code block has three literal backticks _included in the block_, as opposed to ending the block.

Comment: Yea got you was mega rushed earlier, thanks all by the way.

Comment: I'd need a [mre] complete enough to be able to reproduce the problem on my own system (if the code only happens with specific images' exif data, including a link to such an image) to be able to go further.

Comment: After further investigation, it looks as though each value corresponding to each tag needs to be the correct type. Some tags will write some cause a typerror for example if the tag code expects a tuple.